# docker daemon reports 'tls: unconfigured cipher suite' for Nginx reverse proxy of Artifactory Docker registry

Tags: tls, cipher-selection, docker, nginx, ssl-ciphers

I am migrating to Artifactory on RHEL8 as a Docker remote repository, i.e. Artifactory is a proxy for a docker registry hosted through Jfrog.io.

We have a legacy registry with config in `/etc/docker/certs.d/`. Another instance works fine without that config.

There is no proxy between the docker client and the Nginx, which runs on the same host as Artifactory (so [this](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/3176551) does not apply).

The docker client uses TLSv1.2 to connect.

[image: Wireshark]

In Nginx I configured:

```
ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
ssl_ciphers ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384;
```

```
nmap --script ssl-enum-ciphers -p 443 localhost
Starting Nmap 7.70 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2023-11-10 19:52 CET
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.000073s latency).
Other addresses for localhost (not scanned): ::1

PORT    STATE SERVICE
443/tcp open  https
| ssl-enum-ciphers:
|   TLSv1.2:
|     ciphers:
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (ecdh_x25519) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (ecdh_x25519) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256 (ecdh_x25519) - A
|     compressors:
|       NULL
|     cipher preference: server
|     warnings:
|       Key exchange (ecdh_x25519) of lower strength than certificate key
|_  least strength: A
```

When I try `docker login` I get this error:

```
Error response from daemon: Get "https://my-docker-registry/v2/": tls: server chose an unconfigured cipher suite
```

```
docker_version: docker-ce-24.0.7-1.el8.x86_64
```

Reconfiguring crypto-policies to DEFAULT, and lowering Nginx to server over TLSv1.1 & TLSv1.2 did not help. Should Docker have a particular config to get rid of that error message? Or should Nginx be configured in a particular way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> There is no proxy between the docker client and the Nginx, which runs on the same host as Artifactory.

Ensure that the Artifactory host is listed under NO_PROXY in `/etc/systemd/system/docker.d/http-proxy.conf`:

```
[Service]
Environment="HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy.lan:3128"
Environment="HTTPS_PROXY=http://proxy.lan:3128"
Environment="NO_PROXY=artifactory.lan"
```

Answer (score -2):

Run a request to the using `openssl s_client -connect host:port` to debug which cipher suites it is using and which ones you are using https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man1/openssl-s_client.html

You can also experiment with the handshake using s_client.

I made some videos a while back on using s_client, you can also poke around for 'openssl s_client' and lots of help will pop up, but here is my shill: https://youtu.be/Vup8_0UVhn8?si=DLpmTKGmev2tOfxW

Comment: That does not reveal which ciphers the docker client expects.

Comment: Try this one to see which cipher suites the server can use, https://superuser.com/questions/109213/how-do-i-list-the-ssl-tls-cipher-suites-a-particular-website-offers